# Show what task ansible was currently working on when I press Control-C?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible (v2.9.6) playbook with lots of hosts. For some reason, something in my playbook is hanging, or at least taking a very very long time to finish (like 30 minutes). So I press <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop it.

Even with `-vvv` all ansible tells me is `[ERROR]: User interrupted execution`. I am unable to find out what it was "executing", what it was waiting on, when I pressed <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Is there anyway to see what exactly it is 'hanging on'?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of outright killing Ansible with Ctrl/C, try sending it to the background with Ctrl/Z and then inspecting its process tree with `ps f` (or your own favorite `ps` options) to see what it is doing.